# Uso de INNER JOINs con USING, ON o WHERE ( where tabla.column )

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

He aprendido el *USING* haciendo cosas como esta:

```
SELECT nufactura,des,cantidadc,precio,precio*cantidadc AS "SUBTOTAL"
FROM `facturas` INNER JOIN `fac_pro` USING(nufactura)INNER JOIN `productos` USING(codigop)
WHERE nufactura = "700" 
ORDER BY cantidadc DESC
```

pero no he entendido muy bien realmente su orden ni por qué es así, y mucho menos el uso con *ON* y *WHERE* y esa llamada con `nombre.nombre1.` Ese punto no se que hace realmente. ¿Es igual que *FROM*? ¿Es como un puntero o algo así?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando concatenas 2 tablas necesitas indicar que campos son los que relacionan las tablas.

Normalmente se usa ON por defecto:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id_t2 = T2.id
```

En algunos casos los nombres de las tablas son iguales, para ello un atajo es usar **USING**
Supongamos que T1 tiene un campo que se llama id_foo igual que T2 que también tiene un campo que se llama id_foo que las relaciona.

Puedes usar el ON normalmente:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id_foo = T2.id_foo
```

O simplemente usar el USING:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 USING(id_foo)
```

Comment: okok .. en la tercera parte o despues del ON se coloca la tabla y campo con el cual se van a unir y luego se dice que eso es =  a .... (no se como se leería eso ahi se supone que id_foo tambien fue declarada en la T2 cierto? .)

Comment: exacto. Si ambos campos se llaman igual no es necesario escribir los 2